# Using XOR on char array to find if a character is unique in a string

Tags: java, xor

Originally how i solved this CodeWars problem was to use:
`StringUtils.countMatches();`

However, I am wondering if it can be done using XOR on chars?

Here is what i have so far, but it doesn't pass the test and i am quite stumped.

```
static String encode(String word) {
    String test = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] temp = test.toCharArray();
    String sol = "";
    for (char y : temp) {
        if (duplicate(temp, y) == true)
            sol += "(";
        else
            sol += ")";
    }
    return sol;
}

public static boolean duplicate(char[] values, char check) {
    for (char x : values) {
        check ^= x;
        if (check == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method below encodes duplicate characters (starting from the current position!) in a string with `'('` and non-duplicate characters with `')'`:

```
static String encode(String word) {
    String test = word.toLowerCase();
    char[] cc = test.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sol = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
        char c = cc[i];
        boolean duplicateFound = false;
        for (int j = i+1; j < cc.length; j++) {
            char x = cc[j];
            if ((x ^ c) == 0) {
                duplicateFound = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        sol.append(duplicateFound ? '(' : ')');
    }
    return sol.toString();
}

// test
System.out.println(encode("abcabc")); // prints: ((()))
System.out.println(encode("abcdad")); // prints: ())())
System.out.println(encode("abcdfg")); // prints: ))))))
```

The following method passes CodeWars test of detecting all unique characters:

```
public static boolean hasUniqueChars(String str) {
    String test = str.toLowerCase();
    char[] cc = test.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < cc.length; i++) {
        char c = cc[i];
        for (int j = i+1; j < cc.length; j++) {
            char x = cc[j];
            if ((x ^ c) == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just a hint: You're using string concatenation ``sol += duplicateFound ? "(" : ")";`` in a loop – which creates a new String per iteration. It'd be better to use a StringBuilder and ``sol.append(duplicateFound ? "(" : ")");`` instead.

Comment: You're right, that part was a copy-paste from OP's code :)